# open subset of $(0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

The definition of the open subsets is 
$$E \subset \bigcup_{a \in A} O_a\;.$$

Is $O_n = \left(0, 1+\frac1n\right)$ an open cover of $E$?

and if $O_n$ is an open cover of $E$, is $(0,1]$ compact?

Comment: What is all this mumbo-jumbo? You haven't defined any of your symbols. $U$ could be an algebra for all we know.

Comment: You must show every open cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be more careful in your use of notation. An open cover of a set $E$ is a *collection* of open sets; $O_n=\left(0,1+\frac1n\right)$ is just one open set, not a collection of sets, so it cannot possibly be a cover.

Here is what I think you were trying to say:

> Let $E=(0,1]$. A family $\{O_a:a\in A\}$ is an open cover of $E$ if each of the sets $O_a$ is open, and $$E\subseteq\bigcup_{a\in A}O_a\;.$$ For $n\ge 1$ let $O_n=\left(0,1+\frac1n\right)$; is $\{O_n:n\ge 1\}$ an open cover of $E$? Is $E$ compact?

The answer to the first question is *yes*: $O_1=(0,2)$, and $E=(0,1]\subseteq(0,2)$, so $$E\subseteq O_1\subseteq\bigcup_{n\ge 1}O_n\;.$$

In fact, $E\subseteq O_n$ for **every** $n\ge 1$.

The answer to the second question is *no*; see Luis’s answer for a good hint.

Comment: is Luis's example is correct? since (1/n, 1] is not an open. is collection should be an open? is it should be like (1/n,2)

Comment: @Kimchi: The set $\left(\frac1n,1\right]$ is open in the subspace $(0,1]$, though not in $\Bbb R$ itself. If you haven’t learned yet about subspaces and subspace (or relative) topologies, by all means replace his $\left(\frac1n,1\right]$ with $\left(\frac1n,2\right)$, for instance; the example works just as well that way.

Comment: so for for the open cover definition.'open in the subspace' is reliable? and you said i need to more becareful with use of notation cause i did not define the ${O_n : n >= 1}$?

Comment: @Kimchi: Yes, you can use covers that are open in the subspace or covers that are open in the big space: every cover of the first kind has a finite subcover if and only if every cover of the second kind has a finite subcover, so it makes no difference. // The problem with what you said is that it wasn’t actually what you meant. It’s simply not true that $O_n$ is an open cover of anything: it isn’t the kind of thing that *can* be an open cover, because it’s not a family of sets. You meant to talk about the entire collection of $O_n$’s, but you actually talked about only one of them.

Comment: yea I was mean the collection of the On. it make sense thank you

Comment: @Kimchi: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 3):

It is not compact, think about sets of the form $(\frac{1}{n},1]$

Comment: what about [0,1]

Comment: That one is. Look at Heine Borel.

Answer (score 0):

If it was compact, by the finite intersection property every intersection is non-empty. Your set is infinite discrete, and not compact.